# Coldfusion CFquery with Column alias

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am writing a query to pull data from two table and I would like to alias a column on the query. This is generating an error on my end, just wondering if this is possible.

```
<cfquery name="q3" dbtype="query">
    SELECT    *
    FROM    q1, q2
    WHERE    q1.id = q2.id
</cfquery>
```

This works fine however if I try to do this:

```
<cfquery name="q3" dbtype="query">
    SELECT    q1.id as 'AppID'
    FROM    q1, q2
    WHERE    q1.id = q2.id
</cfquery>
```

This will generate an Invalid column index

Comment: What is the error message? It looks like you'll end up with multiple `id` columns, so I would try to list out all the columns and alias as needed to make sure they are unique. Also, not seeing the javascript you tagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to pull data **from two database tables**, you would typically use a cfquery **without** the keyword `dbtype="query"`.  *(Using `dbtype="query"` is for Query of Queries --if you are running a query against the result of a previous cfquery, or a non-database query, like a cfftp directory listing.)* That said, assuming your query is against database tables, using a SQL inner join works fine:

```
<cfquery name="q3" datasource="dbname">
    SELECT  q1.id as 'AppID', q2.id
      FROM  q1 INNER JOIN q2
               ON q1.id = q2.id
</cfquery>
```

This returns only rows from both tables where `q1.id = q2.id`.  If you wanted all of `q1` and any of `q2` where the ids match, you could do a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER join. This would take all the rows from the left table and only the matching values from the right table.

```
<cfquery name="q3" datasource="dbname">
    SELECT  q1.id as 'AppID', q2.id
      FROM  q1 LEFT JOIN q2
               ON q2.id = q1.id
</cfquery>
```

This would return every id from q1 aliased as AppID, and either the id from `q2` if it matched `q1.id`, or else `NULL` if it didn't.)